# Cannot reach outside network or IP after upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ping

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on my server but since the upgrade from 10.04 I can no longer reach any outside sources of the server.

I can SSH into the box, but from inside here I can not reach anything. At least, I can't ping, dig etc.

I have provided everything that I could think that might give me more information, but can't see anything obviously wrong here.

**resolveip**

```
 root@sub:~# resolveip google.com
 resolveip: Unable to find hostid for 'google.com': try again
```

**Ping**

```
 root@sub:~# ping google.com
 ping: unknown host google.com
```

**route -n**

```
 root@sub:~# route -n
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
 0.0.0.0         77.68.108.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
 77.68.108.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**iptables -L**

```
 root@sub:~# iptables -L
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any ideas what has changed since the upgrade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First try to ping your gateway `77.68.108.1`. If you are able to do so, then

I think `/etc/resolv.conf` is not properly configured.

Just open `/etc/resolv.conf` file . At the top of that file, add a line like this:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This is the resolver to which all DNS resolution requests will be directed to. `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are the two open-resolvers which anyone can use.

After this, you should be able to `ping google.com`.

Comment: blow me down, it worked :) Another problem then, I am trying to install plesk for a client. But the server won't hit:  http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ but when using a browser the page opens perfectly. If i ping above it returns host unknown. Any ideas? Been trying for 2 days.

Comment: @JamieHutber you are doing mistake here. You should execute `ping gb.archive.ubuntu.com` but not `ping gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. Can you explain me how are you trying to install plesk ? Are you using some package manager.

Comment: `4.2.2.2` is another big public DNS server.

Comment: Ye sorry, I am using `ping gb.archive.ubuntu.com` not with the trailing `ubuntu`. So i am trying to install ubuntu using the autoinstaller. The problem I get is `500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hardy/main i386 Packages
     release v=8.04,o=Ubuntu,a=hardy,n=hardy,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin gb.archive.ubuntu.com` I follow all of the steps, it adds autointall.plesk.com into my apt-get package. Then as you see gives me a 500 error when trying to download. Been working on it for 2 days now :(

Comment: One more odd thing, i can ping google.com and bbc.com but I can't ping www.ccn.com. Any idea why?

Comment: I'll start a new question relating to the pinging google.com if you don't have any ideas

Comment: @JamieHutber `ping` is not the correct utility to check reachability because ICMP packets may be blocked in many cases. Instead use `tcptraceroute www.cnn.com 80`. This will check the connectivity to 80 port of cnn.com

Comment: My os is ubuntu16. Top of the line says: do not edit, will be overwritten. Is there anyway to modify the DNS?